# An IIS extension before hostname binding occurs?

Tags: iis

I'm looking into IIS extensibility, and was wondering if it's possible to create an extension that sits right before IIS dispatches requests to a hostname? With that I mean:

1) A request comes in, 
2) IIS looks at the hostname header, 
3) decides which site belongs to it,
4) and forwards the request.

I would like to know if its possible to create an extension which sits between 3) and 4).

I've tried looking around on MSDN, but can't really find anything substantial, making me wonder if its possible at all.

The reason I want this is because I'm really tired waiting for wildcard hostname support in IIS*. You can "solve" it right now by having a static IP per website, which becomes very costly at some point. Or you can use a redirect-rule on a default site, but that would break SSL.

In worst case, I can setup a proxy in front of IIS, which does the rewriting before IIS gets a chance, but I would really love it if I can hook right into IIS myself.

*I know it's an upcoming feature for IIS 10, but Windows Server doesn't come with that yet as far as I'm aware.

Comment: As far as I know, this might be impossible because of the HTTP.SYS kernel-mode driver (yup, parts of IIS run in kernel mode). This driver does the initial HTTP packet inspection, validation and dispatches requests to the appropriate userland process based on Host header and Resource path pattern matching.